# Random word generator termination condition malfunctioning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a random word generator that randomly selects a consonant and vowel structure (e.g. 'cvvc' could be 'mean'). It is not working. The problem when I run it in the debugger is at the last two lines at the end of the while loop.

```
import random

vowelsList = ['a','e','i','o','u']

constonentsList = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','th','ch','sh','st','ck']

n = random.randint(1,2)
word = ''
struct = ''
length = 0
x = True
len_con = len(constonentsList)
len_vow = len(vowelsList)
length = 0

while x:
    if n == 1:
        word +=  constonentsList[random.randint(0,len_con - 1)]
        struct += 'c'
        length += 1
    elif n == 2:
        word += vowelsList[random.randint(0,len_vow - 1)]
        struct += 'v'
        length += 1
    n = random.randint(0,2)
    if (length >= 3 & n == 0):    #If the word is more than 3 letters and n == 0, don't continue
        x = False

print(word)
print(struct)
print(length)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to explain what about the last two lines confuses you when debugging. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Hint: There is a `random.choice()` function that'll make it much easier to pick a random value from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually working, albeit only just. The length reflects how many consonants and vowels you produced, but the generated word can be longer as you include two-letter consonants like `th` and `sh`. However, there are improvements to be made.

The `&` operator does not do what you think it does. It is a [*binary bitwise operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations); it sets binary flags in integers:

```
>>> 1 & 1
1
>>> 2 & 1
3
```

You want to use the [`and` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) instead to do *boolean logic AND* testing:

```
if length >= 3 and n == 0:
```

For booleans, using `&` happens to work as the boolean type overloads the operator to return booleans still.

You can greatly simplify your program by using the [`random.choice()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), and move the termination test to the `while` loop condition. The `length` variable is redundant; you can just use `len(struct)` here:

```
import random
import string

vowels = 'aeiou'
consonants = [c for c in string.ascii_lowercase if c not in vowels]
consonants += ['th','ch','sh','st','ck']

n = random.randint(1, 2)
word = ''
struct = ''

while len(struct) < 3 or n:  # minimum length 3
    if n == 1:
        word += random.choice(consonants)
        struct += 'c'
    elif n == 2:
        word += random.choice(vowels)
        struct += 'v'
    n = random.randint(0, 2)

print(word)
print(struct)
print(len(struct))
```